# Почему компилятор запрещает такую специализацию?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Хочу сделать специализацию метода для отдельного контейнера и ввожу такой код:

```
template<typename type, typename container>
struct A
{
    void say();
};

template<typename type, typename container>
void A<type, container>::say()
{
    std::cout << "Say for all" << std::endl;
}

template<typename type>
void A<type, std::vector<type>>::say()
{
    std::cout << "Say for vector" << std::endl;
}
```

Однако компилятор выдает ошибку:

> invalid use of incomplete type 'struct A<type, std::vector >'
> void A<type, std::vector>::say()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы специализируете член, но не саму структуру. Вот он и не понимает — а где сама структура?

Вот [такое вполне работает](https://ideone.com/5jrMKH):

```
template<typename type, class container>
struct A
{
    void say() { std::cout << "Say for all" << std::endl;}
};

template<typename type>
struct A<type,vector<type>>
{
    void say()
    {
        std::cout << "Say for vector" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    A<int,vector<int>> a;
    A<int,double> b;
    a.say();
    b.say();
}
```

Comment: А могу ли я как то обойтись без полной специализации класса и специализировать только метод?

Comment: Не думаю... Но на стандарт сослаться не сумею, тут пусть гуру в стандарте скажут.

Comment: по моему так : `template<typename type> struct A<type,vector<type>> ;`

Comment: @AlexGlebe Не понял, в чем разница? Можно полный пример, скажем, в ideone?

Comment: пока не получается, кажется тут мешает другое количество аргументов шаблона.

Comment: О *могу ли я как то обойтись без полной специализации класса и специализировать только метод?* — вот такой аргумент в пользу категорического нет: специализация — не наследование! в специализации может не быть метода `say` вообще, или это будет не метод, а переменная etc etc. Поэтому без специализации класса фокус не удастся.

Answer (score 1):

Специализация одного члена шаблона класса не разрешается. Для этого надо специализировать весь класс. Однако в данном случае оно и не нужно, так как специализация будет полностью совпадать с основным классом, а все различие сводится к реализации функции `say`. В таком случае следует использовать `if constexpr`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename type, typename container>
struct A
{
    void say(void)
    {
        char const * psz_message{};
        if constexpr (::std::is_same_v<container, ::std::vector<type>>)
        {
            psz_message = "Say for vector";
        }
        else
        {
            psz_message = "Say for all";
        }
        ::std::cout << psz_message << ::std::endl;
    }
};
```